# Login error when creating new appcelerator arrow app

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow, appcelerator-cli

I am using Windows 7 64 bit os, and appcelerator's command-line interface version 5.2.0.

When trying to create an arrow app using the appcelerator command line interface.  I receive an error stating "You are not logged in. Please login again." But I have already logged in!?!? ([see image of command line stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrb4h.png))

It seems that appcelerator is not logging me in correctly.  Anyone have an idea why this is?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug with the latest version of Appcelerator's CLI.  Switching to version 5.1.0 `appc use 5.1.0` allowed me to create the new app.

Comment: So it's a regression. We'd love to fix that for 5.2.1. Could you please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: I've reported the issue for you, it has been reproduced and in the progress of getting fixed: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/CLI-949

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. After peeking into the Arrow code, it looked like it was have trouble finding the .ACS file, which I believe stores the Arrow Cloud creds.

I had to setup a HOME environment variable pointing to my user profile folder, i.e. %USERPROFILE%